# Creating a pool of connections vs 1 permanent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection

So this is more of a generic question but an important one for me and perhaps future googlers.

Since one can create one connection and keep it alive as long as whatever process is connected to it is alive too, and librarys can keep it healthy (upon failing etc) why would one use a pool.

I can not understand where the performance enhancement comes into to play.
The querys are just getting queued the same way they would with one connection.
There is no 'parallel' processing.

Also assuming the process and the DB are in the same server there is no time lost sending the request over the network. In addition no time is lost connecting, and ending the connection with either option.

I can only see the demerits such as making sure the data selected are not currently getting updated by another connection, thus receiving old data etc.

I wanted to boost the performance of my MySQL DB and make it more scalable as I stumbled upon the pool vs 1 permanent connection argument without being sure if I should change or not.